# Unexplained Gap?

Tags: spacing, margins

I'm trying to make a resume CV document, using a various packages for certain things. I'm not sure if I'm not noticing a conflict in these packages, or I'm being stupid when or comes to margins or tables, but I can't get rid of this infuriating gap!

Here you can see an example of the document.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%Packages

\usepackage[a4paper, margin={2.5cm,0cm}]{geometry} %To make it printable
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %For verbose garbage
\usepackage{enumitem} %For the enumerated lists
\usepackage[letterspace=100]{microtype} %For letter spacing
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec} %For customising section headings
\usepackage{color}

%Preamble

\pagestyle{empty}
\linespread{1.2} %increasing line spacing
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\rmfamily \centering \Huge \sc \lsstyle}{}{}{}[]
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\rmfamily \Large \sc \lsstyle}{}{}{}[\color{grey}{\titlerule}\vspace{1ex}]
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.7} 
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newenvironment{coverletter}{\newgeometry{margin=5cm} \rmfamily}{\restoregeometry \newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{coverletter}

Dear Sir or Madam,
\\
Here goes a cover letter.
\
\begin{flushright}
Kind Regards,
\end{flushright}

 \end{coverletter}

%Name title

\part*{kant}
\begin{center}
Address
\\
Email
\end{center}

%Profile

\section*{Profile}
\noindent
\kant[2]

%Education

\section*{Qualifications}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rp{0.75\textwidth}@{}}
Kant &\kant[1]
 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

%Work Experience

\section*{Experience}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rp{0.75\textwidth}@{}}
Kant &\kant[1]
 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

%Skills

\section*{Key Skills}
\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not being very explicit about the problem you see or where the "gap" is, do you mean the space after **Experience** ? That is because the following text is a tabular so can not be broken. It is not really a table so all those paragraphs should not be a tablular then the page break can happen normally.

Comment: `kantlipsum` is not "verbose garbage", but rather philosophical thinking that you're unable to understand! `;-)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It was the preceding coverletter environment...

Answer (score 2):

I increased the top margin so the text stayed just about on the page, and used a list rather than a table to allow better page breaking

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%Packages

\usepackage[a4paper, margin={2.5cm,.5cm}]{geometry} %To make it printable
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %For verbose garbage
\usepackage{enumitem} %For the enumerated lists
\usepackage[letterspace=100]{microtype} %For letter spacing
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec} %For customising section headings
\usepackage{color}

%Preamble

\pagestyle{empty}
\linespread{1.2} %increasing line spacing
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\rmfamily \centering \Huge \sc \lsstyle}{}{}{}[]
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\rmfamily \Large \sc \lsstyle}{}{}{}[\color{grey}{\titlerule}\vspace{1ex}]
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.7} 
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newenvironment{coverletter}{\newgeometry{margin=5cm} \rmfamily}{\restoregeometry \newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{coverletter}

Dear Sir or Madam,
% dont use \\ 

Here goes a cover letter.
% dont use \\

\begin{flushright}
Kind Regards,
\end{flushright}

 \end{coverletter}

%Name title

\part*{kant}
\begin{center}
Address\\% if you must
Email
\end{center}

%Profile

\section*{Profile}
% \noindent not needed
\kant[2]

%Education

\section*{Qualifications}
\begin{description}% list not table
\item[Kant]
\kant[1]
\end{description}

%Work Experience

\section*{Experience}

\begin{description}% list not table
\item[Kant]
\kant[1]
\end{description}

%Skills

\section*{Key Skills}
\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Even using lists latex jumps to a new page when there is room for the next item. That's with margins zeroed out and everything...